# The future of Microsoft Enterprise Library

Tags: enterprise-library

Does anyone know something about the future of Microsoft Enterprise Library? The last version was released in October 2008; will it be in use anymore? or should I watch for another equivalent library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [A Preview of Enterprise Library 5.0 Developer Notes](http://entlib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=EntLib5%20Developer%20Notes).  I don't know if they are still [taking input on features](http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2009/03/27/enterprise-library-5-0-tentative-product-backlog-published-story-feature-prioritization-is-open-your-participation-is-invited.aspx) for 5.0 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at http://entlib.codeplex.com/, you'll see they've released version 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

We've [announced](http://bit.ly/entlibvNext) exploration and planning of the next version of Enterprise Library (6.0). Please read our vision and submit your input on the direction and the scope of the release.

Comment: Enterprise Library 6 has shipped in April 2012. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/04/25/just-released-microsoft-enterprise-library-6.aspx

Comment: Additionally, the project now accepts community contributions. See http://aka.ms/entlibopen

Comment: Is there a roadmap somewhere? I see the latest version is not fully compatible with VS2013 (the configuration editor vsix for instance)

Comment: @Jony, The future direction will be posted on entlib.codeplex.com in the next week or so. Pls stay tuned.